# Changing parameter values according to other parameter choice in Processing script using QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3, parameters

I couldn't find anything about this problem.

Suppose to have the first parameters in a Processing script defined as an `Enum`:

```
   self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
            self.CHOICE,
            self.tr('Choose the parameter'),
            ['param1', 'param2']
        )
)
```

While the second one as a number:

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
        name=self.VALUE,
        description=self.tr('My value'),
        type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double,
        defaultValue=40,
        optional=False,
        minValue=0,
        maxValue=100
    )
)
```

Is it possible to change the minValue, maxValue, description, ecc.. of the second parameter depending on the first or second choice of the first parameter already in the GUI?

e.g. if the user choose `param1` then the second parameter should become:

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
        name=self.VALUE,
        description=self.tr('My value'),
        type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double,
        defaultValue=40,
        optional=False,
        minValue=0,
        maxValue=100
    )
)
```

while if he choose `param2` it should became:

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
        name=self.VALUE,
        description=self.tr('My AWESOME value'),
        type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double,
        defaultValue=0,
        optional=False,
        minValue=50,
        maxValue=500
    )
)
```

Comment: Has this issue been resolved or is there an alternative? This feature would be very useful.

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no support for this in existing QGIS versions (<= 3.8). You'd need to address this at runtime, and add a check that the evaluated parameter value falls into the acceptable range (raising a QgsProcessingException otherwise)